# Maven SpringBoot app starts up from mvn spring-boot:run, but fails with Websphere errors running Spring Boot from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, websphere, jmx

I work on quite a few services with similar architectures, with small differences.  They all use Java 8, Maven, SpringBoot, and Jersey.

I normally debug them in Eclipse (currently on 2021-06) using "Run As->SpringBoot".  This works perfectly fine.  I can also run them from a command line using "mvn spring-boot:run", but that's just an academic exercise, because I prefer to run them from Eclipse.

When I run it from mvn, it successfully starts up, and I can hit listener endpoints (test case is actuator/info right now) with no problem.

When I run it from Eclipse, I get the following mystifying error:

> BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jmx/JmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter]: Factory method 'mbeanExporter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbeanServer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jmx/JmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.management.MBeanServer]: Factory method 'mbeanServer' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.MBeanServerNotFoundException: Could not access WebSphere's AdminServiceFactory.getMBeanFactory/getMBeanServer method; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Notice the last couple of phrases in that.

This service uses an ejb client class that is configured to connect to Websphere EJBs.  One side effect of this is that jmx is not available.  I have to set "spring.jmx.enabled=false".

Note that I went to the trouble of storing the log file for both runs, and I painstakingly compared them, verifying that they were logging the same information (varying by timestamps).  That stacktrace above is the first place where they truly vary.

Curiously, although the Eclipse run shows this error, and listeners do not respond, it doesn't terminate the startup attempt.  The service just sits there, sort of brain-dead.

I'm sure what I've provided isn't enough information, but I'm not sure what else would be useful information.